# Flask Form Won't Write to SQLAlchemy DB

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have created ContactForm as a quick WTForm within my HTML templates. When I go through my application and try to use the contact form to add the name and email values in the ContactForm to my User class it doesn't work. When I query User class in DB I just get empty brackets []. Somebody, please help me!

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('Name', [InputRequired()])
    email = StringField('Email Address', [InputRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name, email):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
    def __repr__(self, name, email):
        return f"{name},{email}"

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET'])
def contact():
    form = ContactForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        email = form.email.data
        user = User(name, email)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    else:
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)

    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Comment: It is likely `form.validate_on_submit()` is `False`. If so, you can inspect `form.errors` after calling `form.validate_on_submit()` to see why.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with methods POST in your route.